# Should I capitalize the main topics of my degree?

Tags: capitalization

I am currently writing a CV. When listing my degrees, I add two bullet points that go into more detail on the main focus of the program. I am unsure whether it is correct to capitalize my degree and within these bullet points. As an example:

BSc in E(?)conomics

- Advanced M(?)icroeconomics
- Asset P(?)ricing and D(?)erivatives

Comment: I like to minimize my upper case text in a CV or a paragraph description of my background (e.g. in an email) -- so I would just capitalize the first word of a line, and proper nouns -- because I think this makes me appear more humble and down to earth, the opposite of someone who brags and makes a big fanfare.  But that's just me.  You get to decide what looks better to your eye.  Make sure you're consistent.

Comment: Normal rules of grammar don't apply to bullet-pointed text on a CV. Just be consistent.

Comment: @aparente001 Countering the modesty of normal discourse, I suggest a CV or resume are the special places to major in Bragging and Fanfare, as marketing pushes.  Then minor in heavy humility at the interview (that you did not get via gentility.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is conventional to capitalize. See for example:

> [Cambridge University](https://www.ice.cam.ac.uk/courses/courses-subject)
> *Courses by subject*
> Archaeology and Landscape History
> Biological Sciences
> Business and Entrepreneurship
> Creative Writing and English Literature
> ...

The reason is that these are course names, proper names, and not just words describing a field of intellectual activity. The intellectual activity itself is not usually capitalized. See for example:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/physics)
> *physics:*
> the scientific study of matter and energy and the effect that they have on each other:
> *nuclear physics
>
> a physics lab
>
> She studied chemistry and physics at college
>
> She's got a physics degree from Warwick University
>
> the laws of physics
>
> Newton's discoveries revolutionized physics
>
> theoretical physics*

Comment: To apply this more explicitly to the OP's concerns: something like *Advanced Microeconomics* should be capitalised if that is the name that the university gave to the programme, course, diploma, etc., but not if it is a part of one's own explanation of what one focused on. If one writes, e.g., that one graduated with 'a specialisation in Advanced Microeconomics', that implies that the specialisation is formally defined in the university regulations; if that is not the case, one should write 'a specialisation in advanced microeconomics'.